# Scale of chart generated by using dc.js is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

I am very new to DC/D3 libraries. I am trying to incorporate DC with ReactJS by having a separate pure JS file that is a reusable D3 component. I am following this [example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web-src/examples/regression.html) here. Here is the dummy data I am using:
[json snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ZR8.png).

This is my App.js:

```js
state = {
        data: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount");
        d3.json("dummy_data.json").then(data => {
            this.setState({data: data});
            console.log("Data is updated!");
        })
        this.createVisualization();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("componentDidUpdate");
        this.updateVisualization();
    }

    createVisualization = () => {
        console.log("createVisualization");
        this.visualization = new Dashboard({
            parentElement: d3.select(this.node)
        });
    }

    updateVisualization = () => {
        this.visualization.updateVis(this.state.data);
        console.log("updateVisualization finished");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{width: '100vw'}} id="app"
                 ref={node => this.node = node}>
                <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And this is my JS file (dashboard.js) used to generate/render chart:

```js
export default class Dashboard {
    constructor(_config) {
        // setting up based on input config
        this.parentElement = _config.parentElement;
        this.initVis();
    }

    initVis() {
        let vis = this;

        vis.chartContainer = vis
            .parentElement
            .append("div")
            .attr("id", "chart-container")
            .style("width", "100%");

        vis.chart = new dc.ScatterPlot("#chart-container");
        vis
            .chart
            .width(768)
            .height(480)
            .margins({top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50})
            .x(d3.scaleLinear())
            .elasticX(true)
            .elasticY(true)
            .brushOn(false) // turn off brush-based range filter
            .symbolSize(8) // set dot radius
            .clipPadding(10);
        const f = vis.chart.x();
        console.log(f.domain());
        console.log("Finish initVis")
    }

    updateVis(newData) {
        let vis = this;
        vis.cf = crossfilter(newData);
        console.log(newData);
        vis.chart
            .on('pretransition', () => {
                // console.log(vis)
                // const xext = d3.extent(vis.chart.group().all(), d => d.key);
                // console.log(newData.map(d => [+d.age, +d.readmission_risk]));
                const r = regression.linear(newData.map(d => [d.age, d.readmission_risk]));
                const m = r.equation[0],
                      b = r.equation[1];
                const [x1, x2] = vis.chart.x().domain();
                const points = [
                    [
                        x1, m * x1 + b
                    ],
                    [
                        x2, m * x2 + b
                    ]
                ];
                const xScale = vis.chart.x();
                const yScale = vis.chart.y();
                const margins = vis.chart.margins();
                console.log(xScale(20));
                var line = vis.chart.g().selectAll('line.regression').data([points]);
                // console.log(vis.chart.x().domain());
                function do_points(line) {
                line
                    .attr('x1', d => xScale(d[0][0]) + margins.left)
                    .attr('y1', d => yScale(d[0][1]) + margins.top)
                    .attr('x2', d => xScale(d[1][0]) + margins.left)
                    .attr('y2', d => yScale(d[1][1]) + margins.top);
                }

                line = line.enter().append('line')
                        .attr('class', 'regression')
                        .call(do_points)
                        .merge(line);
                line.transition().duration(vis.chart.transitionDuration()).call(do_points);

            })
        vis.renderVis();
    }

    renderVis() {
        let vis = this;
        const ageDimension = vis.cf.dimension(d => d.age);
        const ageGroup = ageDimension.group();
        vis.chart.dimension(ageDimension).group(ageGroup);
        vis.chart.render();
        console.log("rendering");
    }
```

I have identified the problem to be the `xScale` in the call-back function in the `updateVis` method. It is returning `NaN`. But I tried to call the `xScale` in the `initVis` the scale function seems working fine and return `[0,1]`. I have been struggling because of this for a long time. Any help would be appreciated!

Update:
Here is a snapshot of the error message I got:[image]

Comment: It’s hard to tell what is going wrong just by staring at code. Are you able to put this where people can debug it, e.g. in a jsFiddle or codepen or whatever? I have looked at this for ~15 minutes but I don’t see anything immediately wrong. Btw have you tried [react-dc-js](https://github.com/dc-js/react-dc-js)? Not sure how to e.g. add a regression line with it, but it provides a nice framework.

Comment: I take it you mean that all uses of xScale in the pretransition handler fail? It’s used a lot in there.

Comment: Yes. If I call something like xScale(20) (or whatever the argument is), it gives me NaN. Sorry I am not be able to set it up on jsFiddle. But I push the broken code to a [Github repo](https://github.com/JasonLi-9933/d3-debugging). Appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for including a reproducible example. It's really hard to debug D3 and dc.js code by just staring at it without running it.

The problem here is that the scatter plot expects the group keys to be a two-element array of numbers, not just a single number. You can see that the `key_function()`, in the regression example which you started from, returns a function returning such keys.

Changing your dimension accordingly:

```
    const ageDimension = vis.cf.dimension(d => [d.age, d.readmission_risk] );
```

caused the chart to appear.

I also had to add the CSS from the example in order to get the regression line to show; I created `dashboard.css`:

```
  line.regression {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 5;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

And added it to `dashboard.js`:

```
import './dashboard.css';
```

Result:

[image: scatterplot with regression line]

Incidentally, the way you have calculated the regression line, it won't update when the data is filtered. If you want it to do so, this should work:

```
const r = regression.linear(vis.chart.group().all().filter(kv => kv.value).map(kv => [kv.key[0], kv.key[1]]));
```

This uses the keys from the chart's group, but only the ones which are filtered "in" (value > 0).